# What is an analogue shift register?

Tags: shift-register

I've been reading about a USB style true random number generator called [BitBabbler](http://www.bitbabbler.org/how.html).  The following screen shot is from a section (linked above) explaining how the device works.  It's been designed by *a group of engineers.*  It apparently uses 11.5 billion electrons to produce a random 3.3V signal.  There's even a 'scope piccy of it working.  Strangely there is no schematic though.  Hmm.

Does anyone have the faintest idea of what an analogue shift register is or how they work?  I suspect that this might be waste from a Bos taurus. Thing is, they sell these...

[image: WTF?]

Comment: Possibly something like the old CCD bucket brigade analog shift registers that were used for audio delay before DSPs?  http://www.geofex.com/sad1024.htm

Comment: Perhaps you could post a message on the EEVblog.com forum, if they can have a look at the website. I'm not an experienced electronics designer, but I do get a weird feeling when reading the text that you show, and reading the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a multitude of designs, but it transfers an analog charge level from one capacitor to another.  There is some noise accumulated in the transfer, but it is usually linear and/or proportional to the input.  The amplifiers used in the transfer circuitry introduce a small DC offset and the amplification is never exactly 1:1.  This means a single stage may for example add a few microvolts and boost the signal a little too much or not enough.  But these will be consistent from one operation to another, so its not random.  Minimizing these losses involves either increasing or decreasing the feedback resistance values.  Increasing them makes the circuit more power efficient but more susceptible to thermal noise and other effects, which are not necessarily truly random.  Decreasing them makes the circuit use more power.  Any stored analog signal will suffer from drift over time, but again, drift is not necessarily truly random either.

Comment: From the link the OP provided, the article?  even says its a sample and hold circuit.  Which is what several posters have suggested may be the case.